# Can we delete the logs older than certain days in log4j other than using MaxBackupIndex

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am using log4j in my application and the logs are getting generated using this framework.

I wanted to delete the logs which are older than 10 days as the logs size is increasing rapidly.

I am aware of the MaxFileSize and MaxBackupIndex which generally deletes based on the number of files generated but my requirement is to delete the logs which are older than certain days. Do we have any option in log4j for this or do we need use some unix script like below and clear the logs?

```
find -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Thanks
Harsha GNS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4j2 supports a [custom Delete action](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover) in the rollover configuration. This should be exactly what you are looking for.

Below is a sample configuration that uses a RollingFileAppender with the cron triggering policy configured to trigger every day at midnight. Archives are stored in a directory based on the current year and month. All files under the base directory that match the `"*/app-*.log.gz"` glob and are 60 days old or older are deleted at rollover time:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="baseDir">logs</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseDir}/app.log"
          filePattern="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
      <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
          <IfFileName glob="*/app-*.log.gz" />
          <IfLastModified age="60d" />
        </Delete>
      </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: thanks. So we don't have this option in log4j right? We have to use log4j2 for this then

Comment: I believe so. You may want to upgrade to Log4j2 anyway since Log4j 1 became End Of Life in 2015 and is known to be broken in Java 9.

Comment: log4j 1.x support this type of deletion

Comment: The `<Delete>` configuration is a Log4j 2.x feature and is not supported in Log4j 1.x.